# Check constraint referencing fields of database object

Tags: django, django-models

Let's say I have a Django object like this:

```
class X(models.Model):
   start_main = models.DateField("start X")
```

And another like this:

```
class Y(models.Model):
    x = models.ForeignKey(X, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    start_sub = models.DateField("start Y")
```

I want to add a CheckConstraint to Y that always ensures that `Y.start_sub >= Y.x.start_main`. Is this possible?

I've looked into django.core.validators.MinValueValidator for example but that only takes concrete values as parameter. I've also looked into the `check = models.Q(...)` syntax but am unable to get syntactically correct constraint.

Comment: No, a `CheckConstraint` always spans the fields of a single table, so that will not work.

Comment: Is there any way to enforce at least runtime checks (not within the database, but in Python code)? In the database I could manually specify such a constraint, for example in PostgreSQL; does this mean only Django doesn't support it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [CheckConstraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/constraints/#checkconstraint) with a [F expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions).

```
class Y(models.Model):
    x = models.ForeignKey(X, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    start_sub = models.DateField("start Y")
    class Meta:
      constraints = [
        CheckConstraint(check=Q(x__start_main__lt=F('start_sub'))), name="x__start_main__lt__start_sub")
      ]
```

Comment: This will noy work since you can not follow `ForeignKey`s in a check constraint.

Comment: Does not work: ERRORS: infrastructure.Y: (models.E041) 'constraints' refers to the joined field 'x__start_main__lt'.